# Download Image from Google Earth Engine `ImageCollection` to drive

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, satellite

I need to download single or multiple images from the collection of ee. (*preferably multiple but I can just put a single image code in a loop*).

My main problem --> **Download every month image from a start date to end date for a specific location (lat: "", long: "") with zoom 9**

I am trying to download historical simple satellite data from the `SKYSAT/GEN-A/PUBLIC/ORTHO/RGB`. This gives an image like -->

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/SKYSAT_GEN-A_PUBLIC_ORTHO_RGB#description

I am working on this in `python`. So this code will give me the collection but I can't download the entire collection, I need to select an image out of it.

```py
import ee
# Load a Landsat 8 ImageCollection for a single path-row.
collection = (ee.ImageCollection('SKYSAT/GEN-A/PUBLIC/ORTHO/RGB').filterDate('2016-03-01', '2018-03-01'))
#pp.pprint('Collection: '+str(collection.getInfo())+'\n')

# Get the number of images.
count = collection.size()
print('Count: ', str(count.getInfo()))
image = ee.Image(collection.sort('CLOUD_COVER').first())
```

Here the `image` contains the `<ee.image.Image at 0x23d6cf5dc70>` property but I don't know how to download it.

Also, how do I specify I want it for a specific location(lat, long) with zoom 19.

Thanks for anything

Answer (score 2):

You can download your whole images in the image collection using `geetools`.

You can install with `pip install geetools`.

Then, change the area, dates, and folder name(if the folder does not exist, it will be created on your drive) and execute this code.

```
import geetools

StartDate= ee.Date.fromYMD(2018,1,16)
EndDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2021,10,17)

Area = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-97.93534101621628, 49.493287372441955],
          [-97.93534101621628, 49.49105034378085],
          [-97.93049158231736, 49.49105034378085],
          [-97.93049158231736, 49.493287372441955]]])

collection =(ee.ImageCollection('SKYSAT/GEN-A/PUBLIC/ORTHO/RGB')
          .filterDate(StartDate,EndDate)
          .filterBounds(Area)

data_type = 'float32'
name_pattern = '{system_date}'
date_pattern = 'yMMdd' # dd: day, MMM: month (JAN), y: year
scale = 10
folder_name = 'GEE_Images'

tasks = geetools.batch.Export.imagecollection.toDrive(
            collection=collection,
            folder=folder_name ,
            region=Area ,
            namePattern=name_pattern,
            scale=scale,
            dataType=data_type,
            datePattern=date_pattern,
            verbose=True,
            maxPixels=1e10
        )
```

Or;

You can use the Earth Engine library to export images.

```
nimg = collection.toList(collection.size().getInfo()).size().getInfo()            
                                  
for i in range(nimg):
    img = ee.Image(collection.toList(nimg).get(i))
    date = img.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd').getInfo()

    task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(img.toFloat(), 
                                          description=date,
                                          folder='Folder_Name',
                                          fileNamePrefix= date,
                                          region = Area,
                                          dimensions = (256,256), 
                                          # fileFormat = 'TFRecord',
                                          maxPixels = 1e10)
    task.start()
```

There are two file formats; TFRecord and GeoTIFF. The default format is GeoTIFF. Also, you can extract images with specific dimensions as shown above. If you want to download images with a scale factor, just remove the dimension line and add a scale factor instead of it.

You can read [this document](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Insert your region of analysis (geom) by constructing a bounding box. Then, use the code below to batch download the images.

```
// Example geometry. You could also insert points etc.
var geom = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[-116.8, 44.7],
    [-116.8, 42.6],
    [-110.6, 42.6],
    [-110.6, 44.7]]], None, False)

for (var i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
  var img = ee.Image(collection.toList(1, i).get(0));
  var geom = img.geometry().getInfo();
  Export.image(img, img.get('system:index').getInfo(), {crs: crs, scale: scale, region: geom});
}
```